# “Google Colaboratory” does not load a Chrome web driver in selenium automation?

Tags: selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver, google-colaboratory, chrome-web-driver

So far I have written the code in Google Colab like this but It just doesn't load the chrome web driver and open a chrome browser.

```
!apt-get update
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin
!pip install selenium
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
```

But it throws an exception stating

> WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
>     (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
>     (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/chromium-browser is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

*"If I set the options to `--headless` it works fine, But I need to load a chrome browser to observe the automation flow."*

Comment: You cannot observe it. Your chrome browser is not the same that colab start in the cloud.